# issue with multiple file downloading with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am making a code for downloading multiple files in a single action which is given below.

```js
function downloadAll() {
 var yourArray = [];
    $( "img" ).each(function( index ) {
   yourArray.push($(this).attr('src'));
 });
 var urls = [yourArray.join(", ")]
 var interval = setInterval(download, 300, urls);
}
function download(urls) {
  var url = urls.pop();

  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.setAttribute('href', url);
  a.setAttribute('download', '');
  a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  a.click();

  if (urls.length == 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filename" style="display: block;">
    <button onclick="downloadAll()">Download</button>
 <img src="http://diegolamonica.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/dlm-logo-small.png" class="image" width="100PX" height="100PX">
 <b class="name">example.png</b>
 <span class="size">(501647 bytes)</span>
 <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/files.cs-first.com/hoc/hoc2017.png" class="image" width="100PX" height="100PX">
 <b class="name">Screenshot (11).png</b>
 <span class="size">(240844 bytes)</span>
</div>
```

but when I try to download it is continuously downloading and never stops and also make undefined files I don't know what is the exact issue.

can anybody help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare var interval inside downloadAll(). So the function download() has no knowledge of this variable. Declae is outside the functions and it should be global known.

```
var interval = '';

function downloadAll() {
    var yourArray = [];
    $( "img" ).each(function( index ) {
       yourArray.push($(this).attr('src'));
    });
    var urls = [yourArray.join(", ")]
    interval = setInterval(download, 300, urls);
}

function download(urls) {
    var url = urls.pop();

    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute('href', url);
    a.setAttribute('download', '');
    a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    a.click();

    if (urls.length == 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply I have tried this code but it only downloads the last image  not all images

Comment: At least the first fault is out. The next might be target '_blank' opening a new window to put the download in. But '_blank' is the label for the new window. So effectively you are using the same window over and over again. Try adding a counter and give each target an unique name.